# Create a batch file to show all file content with file parameters

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt

I would like to create a batch script which will give me parameters like @fname,@fdate,@fsize

i have already used the below

```
@forfiles /p path /m A*.bak /c "cmd /c echo @fsize @fname @fdate,@ftime"
```

but the `@fsize` gives only 10 digit size, not beyond that hence loosing correct information

i have also tried with

```
for %I in (E:\*.txt) do @echo %~znI
```

but it doesn't work in the bat file.

Is there any other option to get only the output not other comments along with it like DIR command. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do a similar job from the command line.  Double all `%` to `%%` to use it in a batch file.

```
for %a in (A*.bak) do @echo %~za "%~na" %~ta
```